# Filter Lambda Function

Tags: python

How do I filter out the letter in the set of words with lambda function?

For example:

I have to filter out every word containing letter "K".

```
["rabbit", "chuck", "Joe", "war", "rock", "docker"]
["chuck", "rock", "docker"]
```

I was told to provide the efforts:

```
list = ["rabbit", "chuck", "Joe", "war", "rock", "docker"]
print(list)
listfilter = list(filter(lambda x: (x == 'k'), lst))
print(listfilter)
```

Comment: You should show your efforts... your attempt and what the problem is you encounter.

Comment: alright i added my code, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your code:

1. The `list` variable name shadows the `list()` builtin -- pick a different name for your original list instead.
2. Your lambda function isn't correct. Instead of `lambda x: x == k`, it should be `lambda x: 'k' in x`.

```py
data = ["rabbit", "chuck", "Joe", "war", "rock", "docker"]
listfilter = list(filter(lambda x: ('k' in x), data))

# Prints ["chuck", "rock", "docker"]
print(listfilter)
```

Comment: But the result I "believe" he is trying to achieve is: `["chuck", "rock", "docker"]` not `['rabbit', 'Joe', 'war']`

Answer (score 0):

Read about Python's [filter](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/filter) function.
Example:

```
words = ['rabbit', 'chuck', 'Joe', 'war', 'rock', 'docker']
filtered_out = list(filter(lambda item: 'k' not in item, words))  # filtered out
print(filtered_out)
```

Comment: Using the `filter` function was not the problem. The problem was to supply a `lambda` that does the correct thing.